# Как сменить браузер поисковика Windows | "Поиск в интернете"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

Поисковик Windows, помимо поиска по файлам, предлагает поиск в интернете.
[image]

Я хочу сменить браузер, а также иметь batch/powershell скрипт для того, чтобы не делать это вручную при переустановке Windows 10.

Интересуем меня именно смена браузера, а не смена поисковика, т.к имеются разные Windows Builds, в которых этот поисковик может быть записан в реестре по-разному, например: `{8C3078A0-9AAB-4371-85D1-656CA8E46EE8}`, `{89418666-DF74-4CAC-A2BD-B69FB4A0228A}`, `{8C3078A0-9AAB-4371-85D1-656CA8E46EE8}`, что делает громоздким скрипт и создает ложные записи в реестре.

Удаление IE11 и Edge, а также смена браузера по умолчанию, в моем вопросе не помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [сообщение от Райана Гевина](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/28/delivering-personalized-search-experiences-in-windows-10-through-cortana/)  в блоге Windows, дам перевод только того, что касается проблемы:

"*К сожалению, в связи с тем, что Windows 10 становится всё популярнее, мы увидели, как некоторые программы нарушают правила Windows 10 и перенаправляют вас к поисковым провайдерам, которые не предназначены для работы с Cortana. Результатом является скомпрометированный опыт, который менее надежен и предсказуем. Непрерывность этих типов сценариев завершения задач нарушается, если Cortana не может зависеть от Bing в качестве поставщика поиска и Microsoft Edge в качестве браузера. Единственный способ, которым мы можем с уверенностью предоставить этот персонализированный, комплексный поиск, - это интеграция Cortana, Microsoft Edge и Bing - все это разработано для того, чтобы сделать ОС удобнее для вас.*

*Начиная с сегодняшнего дня, чтобы гарантировать, что мы сможем предоставить интегрированные возможности поиска, разработанные для Windows 10, Microsoft Edge будет единственным браузером, который будет запускаться при поиске из окна Cortana.*"

Это касается не только Кортаны, как голосового поиска, но и обычного текстового поиска.
Так что штатными средствами - никак. Но, как всегда, если нельзя, а очень хочется, то можно. Например, отлавливать обращение к Edge с помощью [Edge Detector](https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector), который будет отправлять запрос вместо Edge в ваш любимый браузер. Для FireFox есть дополнения, позволяющие при этом перенаправлять запросы к Bing в другие поисковые сервисы (ищите по тегу Bing to, например, [Bing2Google](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bing-2-google/)).
Да, это костыли, но с ними жить удобнее.

P.S. К сожалению, эти костыли придётся ставить заново после каждого большого обновления Windows 10. Я не задумывался, можно ли устанавливать дополнение в Firefox в авторежиме, но EdgeDetector - думаю, вполне.

Comment: Лол (извините) конечно, Кортана не говорит по русски, и соответственно при выборе русского региона она не устанавливается. (Т.е для не англоговорящих этот ответ - отговорка)

Comment: @ДжонатанБлоу Да, поэтому у нас ноут для загранкомандировок куплен в Канаде. Там 2 языка поддерживаются в Кортане - английский и французский.